# How to obtain a full height nested container inside a flexbox column in Safari

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, safari, flexbox

I have a codepen which highlights the issue I'm experiencing:

http://codepen.io/heaversm/pen/rrANWX

I have four columns inside a container with display: flex. The columns receive their style from Bootstrap 3. Inside those columns is a nested container which has a background color. I want that nested container to fill the height of the parent (column) container, but it doesn't work in Safari 10.

[image]

To get it to fill in the other browsers, I give it the following style

`position: relative;
height: 100%;
background-color: yellow`

Works fine in latest FF and Chrome.

[image]

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: possible guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the link from @Michael_B was helpful.

The answer was to add `display: flex` to the columns as well, and remove the `height: 100%` declaration from the nested container, which allowed it to fill the height. Then remove the background color from the column, and apply it to the nested container.